# Is there any simulation software that can be used for simulation circuits of wireless power transfer?

Tags: simulation, electromagnetism

I am searching for a simulation software that also shows the interaction between electromagnetic waves in a wireless power transfer setup.

Answer (score 2):

The best and famous softwares are [Advanced Design System (ADS)](http://www.home.agilent.com/en/pc-1297113/advanced-design-system-ads?&cc=IR&lc=eng) and [ANSYS HFSS](http://www.ansys.com/Products/Simulation+Technology/Electronics/Signal+Integrity/ANSYS+HFSS) and  [COMSOL Multiphysics[RF Module]](http://www.comsol.com/rf-module)

Answer (score 1):

Try COMSOL multiphysics. It can do good electromagnetic simulations. You should provide more details. Is it for energy harvesting?

Answer (score -1):

I think Maxwell software from Ansys can do that perfectly.